# Why doesn't syslog traffic show up in netstat and lsof output?

Tags: syslog, netstat, udp, lsof

I've noticed on my CentOS 5.x system that outbound syslog traffic (UDP) doesn't show up in `lsof` or `netstat` results.

I've even tried stuff like `watch -n .1 'netstat -l -u -n --program'` to make sure I don't miss it. Nada.

Yet I do see the traffic when running `tcpdump port 514 -s 0 -vvv`

Why is that?

Comment: `514` is the destination port, if it's outbound it's probably using something else as a source port.